# B1/B2 Visa Got refused - Possible for Wrong Category

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I Applied for B1/B2 Visa but my activities mentioned were just tourism (B2). Could that be the possible reason as I applied for both categories? They gave me a paper which said I was unable to establish ties with my home country which wasn't true at all, I have a good permanent job, more than 160,000 PKR salary, property on my name, good bank balance, married with 2 kids, property and car as assets and top of that tax return documents.

What could be the actual possible reason for rejecting the visa, I had a travel history (I recently visited UK) as well. When can I again apply for the visa as they have mentioned that I should any apply again as if my circumstances have been changed significantly!

Comment: Did the piece of paper mention under which provision you were refused (e.g. 214(b))?

Comment: yes it was 214(B) unable establish ties, I believe they provide this sort of generic document to everyone, there wasn't anything specific in that yellow paper

Comment: Yes the paper is very generic. Did you ask the interviewing officer for the specific reasons of your refusal?

Comment: Yes I did: Generic Response: Its in the paper which I have provided you, I am totally clueless

Comment: No. US uses a simple rule: B2 visa are gives as B1/B2 and for 10 years. This help/force officer to give visas only when they are sure about truthfulness of application.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzia I have mentioned all my facts and the question which he asked was Purpose / Employment / Married or Not / Visited Any other country and thats all... no document asked or anything!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi whether a successful B-2 applicant receives a B-1/B-2 visa or a B-2 visa depends on the visa officer's discretion and the [reciprocity table](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Visa-Reciprocity-and-Civil-Documents-by-Country.html).  Reciprocity also determines the duration of the visa.  For citizens of many countries, it is five years or shorter.  The "simple rule" you cite does not apply generally.

Answer (score 4):

> I Applied for B1/B2 Visa but my activities mentioned were just tourism
>   (B2). Could that be the possible reason as I applied for both
>   categories?

No. Most people don't even know the difference between B1 and B2 including myself although I kept getting approved for several years. They routinely give out B1/B2 and even if you applied for the *wrong category*, the consular would very likely have pointed it out.

> What could be the actual possible reason for rejecting the visa, I had
>   a travel history (I recently visited UK) as well.

It could be any one of ten thousand different particular reasons. The bottom-line and summary is they don't believe you will return to your home country. Many times there is little method to the madness of US consular officers in issuing visitor visas in particular. Some decision could only be construed as random.

> When can I again apply for the visa as they have mentioned that I
>   should any apply again as if my circumstances have been changed
>   significantly!

You really can apply again even tomorrow although rapid application in succession after refusals usually have increasingly lower probability of success.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply, I am still confused that why should not I return to home country where my wife and 2 beautiful kids are living. I believe its totally depends upon your luck and mood of the Visa Officer, as I had no reason of abandoning my home country If I had to do that I wouldn't have returned back from UK. 
Although what is the cool off period you think, I am thinking to re-apply in July again I was denied in Nov 2018 and do you think its good idea to apply as a whole family or applying alone should be fine?

Comment: There is no cool off period however I agree that six months or more is better. The problem with applying with your family is I do not want the children to have a denial in their passport. What is your nationality? In my country we joke that US consular officers make a decision while you are walking to the counter. I invited my aunt from Ghana, she was very poor, 52 yrs, had nothing, no travel experience & immediately they gave her 5 years. I was shocked, I did not expect she would get the visa. I noticed you visited UK before, means you have travel experience. Apply again in July.

Comment: I am from Pakistan and here it seems like the visa ratio is here around 5% or low, anyways I have some other travel plans for this year, I will be going to UK and Then Australia this year! US is not my dream destination at all that they think I will settle there lolx :P its just a cousin gathering on the new year which I wanted to join nothing else! I'll see if I get the my annuals around new year then may be I will apply Dec this year! thanks mate for your response really appreciate that