# Subclass 600 Visa Refused - Visa Officer Overlook some of the facts what are my options?

Tags: visa-refusals, australia, tourist-visas, pakistani-citizens

I have applied for a tourist visa Subclass 600 which got rejected and I believe that the reasons for this are not correct, and they have overlooked the documents and cover letter I submitted.

Here is the decision:
[image: Decision Letter]

Here is my response to all three allegations:

1. Financial: I have declared my property (residential land) and car
   (worth 1.4 Million) as fixed assets, I agree that money could be
   transferred overseas but I can not sell my property without my
   presence in Pakistan, this nullifies the first allegation.
2. Previous Travel History: I have a valid UK visa which I haven't
   activated yet but I did attach the previous UK visa copy as well
   which was used from OCT 7th 2018 to OCT 12th, 2018. This nullifies
   the 2nd allegation as a visa officer has overlooked this fact as
   well.
3. Employment: I am been working with my current employer for the last 9
   months and with that, I have continuous 5+ years of employment
   history in Pakistan. Also, I have submitted my leave approval letter
   from the office which states that I have to come back to resume my
   duties and if I don't I will be violating my HR policies which could
   result into serious problems for me.

Is there any way I can appeal this decision as I believe the grounds on which my visa is rejected does not stand a chance if someone reviews my application with open eyes.

Comment: Does the refusal letter provide any information about a review or appeal route? Did you provide any evidence of the ownership of your property and how you became its owner?

Comment: Concerning #3: Did you provide evidence of your 4+ years before the recent job?

Comment: @SyedZ Just an observation, but your other questions on TSE eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129965/b1-b2-visa-got-refused-possible-for-wrong-category indicate that recently you seem to have applied for several tourist visas. There may be data-sharing between the various authorities that is flagging this as a pattern and you may be inadvertently giving the impression that you are looking for a way to leave Pakistan (job/property notwithstanding). Perhaps you should build up a travel history to other destinations before trying for the highly sought-after countries.

Comment: Did you provide any documentation for the property ownership? Yes I have submitted the ownership papers
Did I provide previous employment proof? Yes I did experience letter from all previous employers
My Frequent Visa Application:
Applied for USA visa got Rejected
Applied for UK Visa got Accepted
Applied for AUS Visa Rejected

If I have to leave Pakistan, then I already have the UK Visa on my passport why should I be wasting Money on Australian visa? Does not make any sense to me

Comment: @SyedZ Well, apart from the obvious, why did you apply for an Australian visa if you already have plans to visit the UK? The Immigration Officer may have asked him/herself that question. I am just saying that, possibly, making plans to visit Australia on top of intending to visit the UK may not have appeared a ‘normal’ pattern, or perhaps is a pattern that Australian Immigration see as a risk factor. Complete your UK visit as planned (with your family?) then re-apply for Australia with a stronger travel history.

Comment: @Traveller the UK Standard Visitor visa is issued to me to attend a business conference in London, and I applied an Australian visa for tourism purpose as I had an approved leave for my hectic routine. If this is what the Visa Officer has thought then he also overlooked my cover letter cause I explained this in my cover letter too.

Comment: I agree with @Traveller. Your travel plans seem scattergun approach. You’re from Pakistan so you already have a disadvantage. Don’t give any hint of not being a genuine visitor. Build your immigration profile **systematically**

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn I am not arguing with TRAVELLER I a just stating the facts and trying to avoid any mistakes in future and I think if I already have plans for abandoning my country I think the UK is a much better option. Anway's apologies if anyone felt offended I am just trying to discuss the root cause.

Answer (score 3):

[Visitor Visas – Satisfying the “Genuine Temporary Entrant” Criterion](https://migrationalliance.com.au/immigration-daily-news/entry/2015-03-visitor-visas-satisfying-the-genuine-temporary-entrant-criterion.html)

> One of the difficulties with visitor visas is that, in most
>   circumstances, the Department’s decisions to refuse an application
>   **cannot be challenged**.
>
> The right to seek review of the refusal of a visitor visa application
>   is limited to a few narrow circumstances – primarily cases where the
>   applicant is **seeking a visa under the Sponsored Family Stream**. 
>   Thus, in circumstances where no review rights are available, the
>   Department can, and does, seemingly arbitrarily, ignore evidence that
>   would establish that the visa applicant is indeed a “genuine temporary
>   entrant”.

Point #1 shows bias because most people apply for visas with just bank accounts which are liquid. Clearly/she he didn’t want to approve the visa.

From point #2, it is clear the visa officer overlooked your UK visit.

Finally from #3, it’s evident the officer was downright incompetent or biased. Yes you have changed jobs recently, however you have been continuously employed for years. It is different if you were formerly unemployed and just for a job.

**A completely new application is the best (and in this case only) path forward**. Additionally going forward it may be instructive to note that unfortunately most Pakistanis have lots of challenges being approved for visas in most western countries so it is important you submit very thorough applications.

Comment: Is there any way to file a complaint cause I felt offended being classified as possible immigrant (illegally)

Comment: Don’t be offended. It’s nothing personal against you. Every non immigrant visa applicant is first considered as immigrant unless convinced otherwise.

Comment: and in this case I feel like I am convicted :)

Comment: This dejection is understandable after a visa refusal, it happens to most of us. Don't reapply while it lasts. Once you get over that feeling then reapply and address the objections objectively.